# es6 map if the array gets changed

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

```
window.arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
window.arr.map(el=>{
    console.log(el);
});
asyncFunction(){
    window.arr = [ 2, 4, 6 ];
}
```

what will **map** do if **asyncFunction** happens to update the array while map is still running?

Comment: Javascript callstack is single thread, so there would not be such a case `asyncFunction happens to update the array while map is still running`

Comment: nothing. its already run.

Comment: …and anyway, you're **not updating the array**, you're updating **the `arr` variable**. `map` is getting called on an object, and it will continue working with that object, regardless what happens to the variable where that object was looked up from originally.

Comment: async aside, you could explicitly change `window.arr` inside the `map` and it wouldn't affect the outcome of the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off `Array.prototype.map()` is entirely synchronous so the single threaded nature of Javascript will prevent your asyncFunction from running during the time that your `windows.arr.map()` is running.

But, even more interesting is that `window.arr = [2,4,6]` assigns a new array to the `window.arr` variable.  That array has nothing at all to do with the array that `.map()` was working on.  So, even if they could somehow be interwined, the `.map()` operation has its own array and it just keeps working on that array and that array has nothing to do with the new array that was put into the `window.arr` property.

Remember that a statement such as:

```
 window.arr = [2,4,6];
```

doesn't do anything to any array that was previously in `window.arr`.  If anyone else has a reference to the prior array, that array will still exist just fine and be unaltered.

Here's a simple demonstration:

```js
let a = [1,2,3];
let b = [4,5,6];
window.arr = a;
console.log(a);
window.arr = b;
console.log(a);
```

From this, you can see that array `a` was not changed at all when `window.arr` was reassigned.  So, in your example, it was array `a` that `.map()` was running on.